# Double layered shrinkwrap onto a sphere

Tags: modeling, mesh, shrinkwrap

[image]

I want to have this character's eyes shrink-wrapped to their head, and for the pupils to be shrink-wrapped onto the eyes, however, every time I try this, the pupils end up looking like this image.

[image]

Does anyone know what I can do to make the pupils keep their circular shape while being able to move them around?

Comment: Keeping the existing circular shape, on what you have?  Change your shrinkwrap modifier from Nearest Surface Point to Project, enable both negative and positive directions, change snap to Outside Surface or Above Surface, and set the axis to Y (assuming local axes for the object that agree with world axes.)  Further problems, people would want a file to troubleshoot.

Comment: Thanks so much!